# Crystal Report issue when summing fields

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I have a main and subreport. After I fill my dataset fields, I put my field inside subreport. But When I try to `sum()` of this field, I am getting an error like

> this field must be number or currency

How can I solve this problem? (I even set the my dataset field as decimal but nothing changed)

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth giving the function Tonumber a go. I've had similar issues in the past and this seems to have sorted them.

Syntax:

```
ToNumber({YourField})
```

Comment: thank you your answer,it orks fine but now I have a issue to get the subreport value  from th main report.I try this one but I am getting  zero value.http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?449494-How-to-get-formula-field-value-from-Subreport-to-main-report

Comment: Try to link the main report fields and subreport fields with a common field like ID or Key or use Shared variables

Answer (score 0):

May be you are trying to sum a String filed.

If that is not the case then explain more in detail will try to help you.

Comment: Iset the my dataset field as decimal but nothing changed

Comment: when I use a formula like this ,WhileReadingRecords; 
$CCur ({ParcaUcreti.Tutar}),but in this case I coulnt sum() of this formull like thta.WhileReadingRecords; 
sum($CCur ({ParcaUcreti.Tutar}) ) I dont know whats wrong

Comment: Problem I see here is "$CCur " will retun currency as output which can't be summed using "sum" as sum needs a number